# elasticsearch aggregation result key filter from field or fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using elasticsearch 1.7 and i have to find filter must not from aggregation key value
Below is the structure :

```html
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"bl","zi":"z101"} 
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"bl","zi":"z102"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"bl","zi":"z103"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"un","zi":"z201"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"un","zi":"z202"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"g1","zi":"z101"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"g1","zi":"z502"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"g2","zi":"z201"}
{"RU": "2016-06-25T15:07:46.144","zt":"g2","zi":"z503"}
My query :
    {"size": 0,
       "aggs": {
          "findunique": {
             "filter": {
                "bool": {
                   "must_not": [
                      {
                         "terms": {
                            "zt": [
                               "bl",
                               "un"
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   ],
                   "must": [
                      {
                         "terms": {
                            "zt": [
                               "g1",
                               "g2"
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             },
             "aggs": {
                "uniquezi": {
                   "terms": {
                      "field": "zi"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
 }
-------------------------------------------------------
output :
 {"aggregations": {
      "findunique": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "uniquezi": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "z101",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "z201",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "z502",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "z503",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}}
```

Now i am looking to don't show zi =z101 and z201 should not come in list as that belonging to zt = bl and zt = un
Please suggest me Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you could try adding two aggregations with filer set on "zt" field. 
This way you will get two sets and can extract all from "Wanted" which are not in  "Unwanted" later in code.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : {
          "wanted" :   { "terms" : { "zt" : [ "g1", "g2" ] }},
          "unwanted" : { "terms" : { "zt" : [ "bl", "un" ] }}
        }
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "monthly" : {
            "terms": {"field" : "zi"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "messages": {
      "buckets": {
        "wanted": {
          "doc_count": 4,
          "distinctValuesAgg": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "z101",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z201",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z502",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z503",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "unwanted": {
          "doc_count": 5,
          "distinctValuesAgg": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "z101",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z102",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z103",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z201",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "z202",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much Tomasz for quick response ! but i am getting following error : nested: SearchParseException[[ulttronlist][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Expected [FIELD_NAME] under a [START_OBJECT], but got a [START_OBJECT] in [Wanted]]]; }{[EGOcq-dvTteB7jBQG0aeGQ][ulttronlist][4]: SearchParseException[[ulttronlist][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot set elastic server locally to run it right now, if this solution could be acceptable I'll try later today to fix the code and provide it to you.. It must me some typo..

Comment: ok thanks Tomasz, i will wait .. because i was doing and trying to get success .. but didn't ..

Comment: Hi Tomasz Please help me to find solution as still not result.:(

Comment: Hi Gawlik, Thanks bro for ur help. but i need unique value of zi which blongs to "g1" and "g2" but not belongs to "bl" and "un"...so i have find out unique zi with aggs but not able to filter those bucket key value from bl and un.... so please help me

Comment: yes, my idea was to query elastic and get those two sets: A (Wanted), B (Unwanted). Later in code you could perform {A} \ {B} to get your data. I don't know how you could get it in one query.